# Execute a stored procedure as another user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions

I have the following problem: there's a user, *A*, who has to execute a stored procedure (`spTest`). In `spTest`'s body, `sp_trace_generateevent` is called.

The problem is that `sp_trace_generateevent` requires alter trace permissions, and I don't want user *A* to have those permissions. I would still like user *A* to be able to execute `spTest`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXECUTE AS user = 'special_user'

EXECUTE YourProcerdure

REVERT
```

See these links for more information:

- [Understanding Context Switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191296(v=sql.105))  <- has examples of things like you are trying to do
- [Understanding Execution Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187096(v=sql.105))
- [`EXECUTE AS` Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql)
- [`EXECUTE` AS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql)

Comment: For some reason it does't help. I get error that i don't have permission to run sp_trace_generateevent. But when I connect to the server as special_user I have no problems to execute sp_trace_generateevent. Any ideas?

Comment: from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx The user or login name specified in EXECUTE AS <context_specification> must exist as a principal in sys.database_principals  or sys.server_principals, respectively, or the EXECUTE AS statement fails. Additionally, IMPERSONATE permissions must be granted on the principal. Unless the caller is the database owner, or is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the principal must exist even when the user is accessing the database or instance of SQL Server through a Windows group membership.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't help neither. It appeared that I should turn on TRUSTWORTHY. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested you can achieve what you wish using the Execute As clause. For examples of implementation choices take a look at the Books Online documentation for the [Execute As](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) clause.

For further reading and to develop more understanding of this topic, what you are looking to achieve comes under the security concept of [Context Switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188268.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did (and succeeded):

```
let Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", 
    [Query= "EXECUTE AS USER='user' EXECUTE [schema].[spname] 'parm1', 'parm2'"])
```

in

```
Source
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answers, which already give the solution of `Execute As User= 'user'`

Answer (score -2):

When you go to execute that specific stored procedure you will need to create a different connection using the needed user credentials.

Comment: For some reason it does't help. I get error that i don't have permission to run sp_trace_generateevent. But when I connect to the server as special_user I have no problems to execute sp_trace_generateevent. Any ideas?